# Input text inside a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create an input text inside a react component and then I realised that it's a bad praxis. So I investigated a little bit so I found [Controlled-Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), so I think this is what I need, but looking at my `Component` I do not know how to create it.

I do not have an `extends Redux.Component` so a friend suggested me to create a [Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#extracting-components) but couldn't get succeed.

What I was trying is this :

Inside my `component`

```
 <input
        ...
      />
      {"  "}
      <input
        ...
      />
      <span>
        <myButton
          ...
          arguments={[document.getElementById("id1").value, document.getElementById("id2").value]}
        >
          [ send ]
        </myButton>{" "}
      </span>
```

But I'm getting this error :

> The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!

### EDIT

On my component where I have all of those code I have this :

```
 <myButton
          id={id}
          arguments={[intputStuff]}
        >
```

So my problem is if I do what Tom's says I do not have the id in the other component.

So the thing should be create this component inside the other component and then get the values of the inputtexts and put them as an arguments

Comment: That is not how reactjs works. Tom's answer is the correct react pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your post what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

It appears that you're trying to build a component with 2 text inputs and a button.

If you want the button to "submit" the values of the two inputs, you should do something like this:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            value1: props.initialValue1,
            value2: props.initialValue2
        }
    }


    onChangeText = (event) => this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })


    onClickSubmit = (event) => {
        let { onSubmit } = this.props
        if(typeof onSubmit !== 'function') return

        let { value1, value2 } = this.state
        return onSubmit([ value1, value2 ])
    }


    render() {
        let {
            initialValue1,
            initialValue2,
            onSubmit,
            className,
            ...props
        } = this.props

        let {
            value1,
            value2
        } = this.state

        return (
            <div className={`SomeComponent ${className}`} {...props}>
                <input value={value1} name="value1" onChange={this.onChangeText} />

                <input value={value2} name="value2" onChange={this.onChangeText} />

                <button onClick={this.onClickSubmit}>
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

A few notes:

1. This example uses a bunch of futuristic JS: destructuring, rest/spread, class properties, computed property names, and arrow functions. Each feature is being leveraged for a specific purpose, not just because they're cool. If your environment doesn't support some of these features, you'll need to find a workaround that makes good on some additional constraints.
2. This is not a controlled component, but it does contain 2 controlled inputs. It uses the "initialValue" pattern: the owning component provides starting values, but is unaware of the blow-by-blow as the user types each character. The owning component is only notified of the new values when the button is clicked. This pattern can result in loss of data if the owner is re-rendered before the current value are submitted.
3. Generally, when using React, you want to avoid using native DOM methods to access or manipulate elements. (There are plenty of exceptions, of course.) One reason you want to avoid native DOM methods is that component lifecycle methods might execute before the React renderer has actually updated the DOM -- so `document.getElementById('someid')` might return `undefined`.

Comment: But I have already a button so I need to send those inputs as an argument to my button

Comment: If you want to provide the button with the values of the two inputs, you can do that easily: `<MyButton arguments={[ value1, value2 ]} />`

Comment: Problem is, that I need 2 more sutff that are on my other component class is there any way to get the buttom to other class ?

Comment: I think you are going to need provide more detail in your post. It's obvious from these comments that you have additional constraints and goals that are not described in sufficient detail for the rest of us to work through them. SO doesn't usually let people do a lot of back-and-forth tech support in comments. My advice: post your whole component, not just _part_ of the content of your `render` method. Also, describe the API of your custom `<MyButton>` component: what props does it accept and what are their types.

Comment: @StuartDTO I don't know what that `id` parameter is for, or what it is supposed to reflect. In React, use of `id` is strongly discouraged. If you need to provide a value for `id` because a Java-based HTTP endpoint requires it, can't you just hard-code the value? Or pass it down from the owner? Or have the owner bundle that value in as the rest of the payload goes out the door?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184234/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-tom).